# sudo apt-get install libstdc++

Tags: apt, gcc

When i try to install `libstdc++` using:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++
```

I am getting the below error in ubuntu. Do you have any idea about it?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-4.8-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++-4.9-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++-4.8-doc but 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++-5-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++-4.8-doc but 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
                   Conflicts: libstdc++-4.9-doc but 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04 is to be installed
                   Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-doc but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-doc : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-doc but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-doc but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.7.3-11ubuntu1cross1.85 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.9-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg but 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-5-dbg : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg but 4.6.4-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.3-12ubuntu1 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg but 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.9-dbg but 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you recently add any ppas?

Comment: There isn't actually a package called `libstdc++` (possibly you are trying to install `libstdc++6`? Because of the `++` characters, when `apt` doesn't find an exact match it treats the package name as a *regular expression* so in this case it's trying to install any package whose name matches `libstd` followed by one or more `c` - many of which conflict, as you can see.

Comment: @steeldriver: that is clearly the answer and imho should be an answer rather than a comment (although it would help to be able to explain how to avoid treating the string as a regex). The manpage for `apt` says that it will treat package names as regexes if they include `.`, `?` or `*` without mentioning `+`, so the behaviour is not exactly expected.

Answer (score 18):

There isn't actually a package called `libstdc++` (possibly you are trying to install `libstdc++6`?)

When apt doesn't find an exact match to a package name, it treats the given string as a regular expression. In this case the `++` causes it to try to install *any* package whose name matches `libstd` followed by one or more `c` - many of which conflict, as you can see.

Unfortunately I have never managed to figure out how to turn off this behaviour (nothing I have tried in the past using escape characters has seemed to work) - the only solution I know is to be careful to give an exact package name where any regex characters might be misinterpreted, and to make sure the package catalog is up-to-date i.e.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: this should be accepted. Concerning the turn-off: one could write an alias or function which wraps the package name inside a `^PACKAGE$`

Answer (score 14):

First run these commands

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and then try

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

or try this search result and install one desired package from listed http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B

Comment: +1 Good answer, but isn't the `libstdc++` included in the `build-essential`s?

Comment: Oh and why installing `aptitude` if you don't use it for installing `libstdc++6`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kev. I tried to give some sort of possibilities in case of not success. And aptitude for handling his error.

Comment: sudo apt-get update
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: invalid ELF header

Answer (score 3):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

Comment: Could you explain why the user must do this and what each command does?  (just in case someone else reads your answer and decides to just copy-paste it for the wrong problem?)  **;-)**